# Grails constraint constraint on int column throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: validation, grails, constraints, grails-orm

I have following constraints on two integers, score and numOfQuestions.

```
score blank:false, min:1, nullable:false, notEqual:null
numOfQuestions blank:false, min:1, nullable:false, notEqual:null
```

As it can be seen I want these fields to be greater then 0 and should not be null or blank but regardless of what I do, rather then showing a friendly message like "property can not be blank" my screen gets filled with long exception...
Is there any other way to validate integers for non blank inputs?

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property numOfQuestions; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int] for property numOfQuestions: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [null]
```

I have seen this http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4603 but didn't help much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can replace the constraints above with just:

```
score min:1
numOfQuestions min:1
```

Because `min:1` implies not-null. The constraint `blank: false` can only be applied to `String` properties, so you're use of this constraint with a numeric property is probably responsible for the exception you're seeing.

Comment: Plus `nullable:false` is the default, so specifying it is redundant.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Hey I am not sure why is it not working but I am getting this exception all I have is score min:1 in constraints!                                   Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property points; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int] for property points: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [null]

Comment: what's the variable type of `score`?

Comment: @Grrrrr you cannot use the `min` constraint with String-typed properties